# Jquery Code help

Tags: jquery

I wrote a jquery script:

```
$(document).ready(function(){  
$("#category").click(function(){  
    $("#category_menu").slideToggle(1000);  
    });  
  $("body").click(function(){  
    $("#category_menu").hide();  
  });  
});
```

My Question is, is there any way to reduce the size to look more "professional" ?

Comment: In my experience, people seem to consider bigger code more professional!

Comment: Professional to me is efficient and well-documented.  And I would take well-documented over efficient most days...

Answer (score 1):

the only way i can see to reduce it is to do:

```
$(function(){  
   $("#category").click(function(){  
       $("#category_menu").slideToggle(1000);  
    });  
    $("body").click(function(){  
       $("#category_menu").hide();  
    });  
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Anything clicked on that's not `#category` will hide `#category_menu`. You also don't need document ready function if you place your jQuery just before `</body>`

```
$("#category, html").click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    this.id == 'category' ? $("#category_menu").slideToggle(1000) : $("#category_menu").hide();
});
```

Check working example at http://jsfiddle.net/QDfnh/1/

Comment: Not sure this would work, would it - since if (for example) `body` is clicked - this won't trigger? Maybe I'm missing something. Shouldn't it be something like `$("*").click(function(){...});`

Comment: How will `this.id` ever be anything other than `#category`?

Answer (score 1):

First you should use the `document.ready` shortcut and alias `jQuery` to `$` to allow cross-library support, and you can store the `#category_menu` lookup to expedite the functions. But really your code is fine as-is.

```
jQuery(function($){
  var $cm = $('#category_menu');
  $('#category').click(function(){
    $cm.slideToggle(1000);
  });
  $('body').click(function(){
    $cm.hide();
  });
});
```